# SSRS: Show images from multiple rows at once

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

From a database I get information about collaborators. The collaborators can have a different number of images. E.g. one collaborator has four images, another one only one. In this example I would get 5 rows in total. Four for the first collaborator, differing only in the image and one row for the other collaborator.

My report should treat all images belonging to the same collaborator as the same result row. So the first collaborator will have four images on its report and the other one only one. At the moment one report per row is created.

How can I tell SSRS that all rows which differ only in the image column belong together and how can I add these images to the report?

I must admit I haven't tried much yet because I don't know where to start. I've read about the previous() function (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/397c92f5-e533-47be-9e07-56ea0b19f9a7/merge-data-from-multiple-rows-into-one-in-ssrs) and the instr() function ([multiple images in SSRS Table Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746068/multiple-images-in-ssrs-table-cell)) but both are so far I see not what I need.

If necessary I guess I could merge the rows already in MSSQL to have one row per collaborator with comma separated images.

The images are not stored as file names but in binary form.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to utilize groupings to keep the images of the same collaborator together.